# install Multimedia codecs, flash on linux

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, codec

i had **easylife for fedora** that it can install codecs and flash and some other software very easily. i want to know: is there like this tools for **Debain**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `w32codecs` (or `w64codecs` on an amd64 system) and perhaps other packages from the [Debian multimedia](http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ repository). Write the following in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-multimedia.list`:

```
deb http://www.debian-multimedia.org stable main
deb-src http://www.debian-multimedia.org stable main
```

(Replace `stable` by `testing` or `unstable` if needed.) Then run `apt-get update` (or `aptitude update` or click “Update” in Synaptic) and install the extra packages.